# mysql wildcards both sides of like operator

Tags: mysql, wildcard, bidirectional

OK, This may be a silly question.

I am doing some string matching... specifically normalized patient data matching. So I have to patient databases and want to match a string from one to the other.  But I have normalized strings on both sides.

as an example, I make everything lowercase, strip out alphanumerics, trim the names to the first 3 characters and for any name strings that dont have 3 characters I fill them with "_" to act as a wildcard.

here is an example name and normalized name with DOB:

```
DB1: John A Smith 4/27/2011     -->   joha__smi04272011
DB2: John Smith 4/27/2011       -->   joh___smi04272011
```

so now I use like:

```
select 'joha__smi04272011' like 'joh___smi04272011';
```

is True

```
but select 'joh___smi04272011' like 'joha__smi04272011';
```

is False

I want to do both comparison on one Db yielding True if either is True.

Certainly would mean that the underscore would be a wildcard on both sides of the like.  I considered an or and that does it but i cant use that to query a database, or if I can, I cant wrap my head around it in practice...

does this do what I am looking for?  I just seems so odd:

I am looking for the local ID in `drdata` and iterating though and sending queries from the other database

```
select localid from drdata where microid like 'joh___smi04272011' or 'joh___smi04272011' like microid;
```

It just seems too crazy to be the right way to do this.  Drawbacks?  Reommendations?  I have run the query and it seems to match bidirectionally using wildcards on either side of the 'like'

thanks.

Comment: So I guess the issue is the underscore regarding the string match?

Comment: yes... i want to use wildcards both directions.  I am going to run it again in a few minutes with that inverted like combined with an or.  I am trying to increase the sensitivity of the match.

Comment: I am not sure if it is possible to do. I think, better to replace the underscores to match the strings like REPLACE(Col1, '_',  '').

Comment: Replacing the underscores wont work.  Look at the example above... if the middle initial or name is ommitted it wont match  You need placeholders that are single character wildcards.  Incidentally, I did that bizarre bidirectional like and it worked perfectly.  Increased my sensitivity fro 92.6% to 96.6%.